# How can i pivot a dataframe in pandas where values are date? I get DataError: No numeric types to aggregate error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot a Dataframe in Pandas but I get DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.
I have data that looks like :

```
Year,Country,medal,date
1896,Afghanistan,Gold,1/1/2012
1896,Afghanistan,Silver,1/1/2012
1896,Afghanistan,Bronze,2/3/2012
1896,Algeria,Gold,3/4/2012
1896,Algeria,Silver,4/3/2012
1896,Algeria,Bronze,5/4/2012
```

What I want is:

```
Year,Country,Gold,Silver,Bronze
1896,Afghanistan,1/1/2012,1/1/2012,2/3/2012
1896,Algeria,3/4/2012,4/3/2012,5/4/2012
```

I tried

> medals = df.pivot_table('date', ['Year', 'Country',],
> 'medal').reset_index()

I get DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use pivot instead of pivot table. check which one is index/column/value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `aggfunc` in this case, because it tries to aggregates a numeric column:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Country'], 
               columns='medal', 
               values='date', 
               aggfunc=lambda x: x).reset_index()

medal  Year      Country    Bronze      Gold    Silver
0      1896  Afghanistan  2/3/2012  1/1/2012  1/1/2012
1      1896      Algeria  5/4/2012  3/4/2012  4/3/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pivot_table` is good for aggregating data, but they need to be numerical. In your case, you should rather use `.pivot` as follows:

```py
df.pivot(index='Country', columns='medal', values='date')
```

Comment: Hi, if we add multiple column in df, do we use list of columns?

Comment: Do you mean to add other columns for which to display data like 'data' or columns to be used as 'medal' ?

Answer (score 0):

To your code, just add **"aggfunc=np.sum"**

df.pivot_table('date', ['Year', 'Country'], 'medal',**aggfunc=np.sum**).reset_index()